# English speaking doctors in Saarbrücken

Tags: germany, health-care

I've been living in Saarbrücken for over a year and I am yet to find a good English speaking doctor. I have looked at many online links with them all leading me in circles or suggesting doctors who I know don't speak English! I'm having some slightly more complicated health queries where I need a doctor with good English and not just the basics. I've tried a few here, but they either don't speak good enough English or I really haven't liked them. Any recommendations would be so much help. Even if it is in the surrounding areas, I'm fine with traveling if they are good.

Comment: You might consider hiring a local student to translate for you if it is not a frequent thing.

Comment: Depending on whether you’re working in Saarbrücken and if so, where, you may be able to get advice from your colleagues. Unfortunately for you, unless somebody actually is in Saarbrücken and has already found one — unlikely given the small size of this user base — we probably won’t be able to answer. Sorry. (Also note that ‘Good English-speaking’ is relatively rare in Germany altogether)

Answer (score 2):

The US Consulate General in Frankfurt list of doctors and hospitals in [Saarland includes eight krankenhäuser und kliniken in Saarbrücken](https://photos.state.gov/libraries/frankfurt/1020130/spahncx/List%20of%20Doctors%20and%20Hospitals%20in%20Saarland.pdf).

The [International Max Planck Research School](http://www.imprs-cs.de/lis/admin/medicine.html) offers a list of English-speaking doctors.